# Strategy for Looping Through a Fixed Set in Javascript by Steps

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out a way in JavaScript to advance and rewind through a fixed set by steps.

`[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

I'm starting at `3`.  I want to advance by `15`.  That means I land on `7` because after `10`, we start over again at `0`.

Another example.  Starting at `9`, rewind by `11`.  I should end up on `9` again because after `0` we start over again at `10`.

Basically, as you loop you fall of the edges of the set and start again on the opposite edge continuing in the same direction.

This should work for any size set, not just one with 11 elements like in the example.

Help me, math wizards! ‍♂️

Comment: `index = (index + 1) % size;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally for any language what you want is the modulus operator `%`. The problem the behavior for negative numbers is not defined as some would expect. One way to deal with this:

```js
function move(start, step, size) {
  return (start+step+Math.abs(step)*size)%size
}
  
console.log(move(9,-11,11))
console.log(move(3,15,11))
```

where step can be either positive or negative. Another I think is:

```js
function move(start, step, size) {
  res = (start+step)%size;
  if (res < 0) return size + res;
  return res;
}

console.log(move(9,-11,11))
console.log(move(3,15,11))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get the index, add the wanted steps and take from the sum the remainder with the length of the array as index.

If the index is negative add the length of the array.

```js
function getValue(array, start, steps) {
    var index = array.indexOf(start);

    if (index === -1) return;

    index += steps;
    index %= array.length;

    return array[index < 0 ? index + array.length : index];
}

var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

console.log(getValue(array, 3, 15)); // 7
console.log(getValue(array, 9, -11)); // 9
```